# Is @ManyToOne's "optional" param automatically set using Kotlin's nullability

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, data-class

I read that specifying `optional = false` in the `@ManyToOne` association annotation could help Spring improve the performance of the queries.

In a Kotlin data class entity, do I actually need to specify the parameter in the annotation, or can Spring figure this out by itself using the nullability of the `item` field?

For instance, if I have the following declaration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ACCESS_LOGS_ARCHIVES_TABLE, indexes = [
    Index(name = "access_logs_archives_item_idx", columnList = "access_item_id")
])
data class AccessLogArchive(
    val date: LocalDate,

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "access_item_id", nullable = false) 
    val item: AccessLogItem,

    val occurrences: Int
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null
}

@Entity
@Table(name = ACCESS_ITEMS_TABLE)
data class AccessLogItem(
    @Column(length = 3) val code: String,
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text") val path: String,
    @Column(length = 10) val verb: String
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

In this case, I would for instance expect Spring to know that the `item` field is not nullable, and thus the relationship should be understood as `optional=false` even without specifying it as I did. Is this the case?

Same question goes for the `@JoinColumn`'s `nullable = false`, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple entity like a `Room` which has a `@ManyToOne` relationship to `House`.

```
@Entity
class Room(
        @ManyToOne(optional = true)
        val house: House
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long = 0
}
```

JPA will create a room table with a column

```
`house_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
```

If you specify `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`

the column will look like this:

```
`house_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
```

By specifiying optional you tell JPA how the schema should be generated, whether the column can be `NULL` or not.

At runtime trying to load a `Room` without a `House` will cause an Exception if the house property is not nullable (`House` instead of `House?`) even when value of `optional` is `true`.

The same applies to `@JoinColumn`.

> Is @ManyToOne's “optional” param automatically set using Kotlin's
>   nullability?

No it is not. It is independent from that and by default set to `true`.

**Conclusion:** In order for you schema to reflect your entities it is a good idea to use `optional = true` if the house property would be nullable and `optional = false` if the house property would be non-nullable.